# Frozen Black Screen after suspension And Static Brightness in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 18.04, 20.04

I have a problem ever since I started using Ubuntu a year ago with Ubuntu 18.04 with the suspension and brightness of my laptop and even though some friends told me that, with the actualization from 18.04 to 20.04, the problem would be solved, it didn´t happen at all. Honestly, I didn´t pay much attention to this problem ´till now so I´m a bit lost in this topic. My screen keeps getting frozen just after a suspension so I tried to implement the hibernation instead, complicating it all and about the topic of the brightness I get to move the regulation bar but the brightness keeps being the same. To be honest, I´m not an expert in this OS. I´m only begining in this world so it would be of big help anything that you could suggest me to solve this problems.
If it is of any help, below will be my laptop specifications after running the command inx -Fxnzr. Thank you so much.

```
Sistema:

Kernel: 5.4.0-47-genérico x86_64 bits: 64 compilador: gcc v: 9.3.0 Escritorio: Gnome 3.36.4 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)

Máquina:

Tipo: Laptop Sistema: ASUSTeK producto: VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X512DA_X512DA v: 1.0 serial: Mobo: ASUSTeK modelo: X512DA v: 1.0 serial: UEFI: American Megatrends v: X512DA.305 Fecha: 16/07/2019

Batería:

ID-1: Carga BAT0: 18,4 Wh Condición: 32,5 / 37,1 Wh (88%) modelo: ASUSTeK ASUS Estado de la batería: Cargando

UPC:

Topología: Modelo de cuatro núcleos: AMD Ryzen 5 3500U con Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx bits: 64 tipo: MT Arco MCP: Zen + rev: 1 caché L2: 2048 KiB banderas: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm bogomips: 33535 Velocidad: 1342 MHz mín. / Máx .: 1400/2100 MHz Velocidades del núcleo (MHz): 1: 1397 2: 1397 3: 1222 4: 1222 5: 1397 6: 1397 7: 1222 8: 1222

Gráficos:

Dispositivo 1: Proveedor de AMD Picasso: Controlador ASUSTeK: N / A ID de bus: 03: 00.0 Pantalla: servidor x11: X.Org 1.20.8 controlador: ati, fbdev descargado: configuración de modo, radeon, vesa resolución: 1920x1080 ~ 77Hz OpenGL: renderizador: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0 128 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 20.0.8 render directo: Sí

Audio:

Dispositivo 1: controlador de audio AMD Raven / Raven2 / Fenghuang HDMI / DP: snd_hda_intel v: ID de bus del kernel: 03: 00.1 Dispositivo-2: AMD Raven / Raven2 / FireFlight / Renoir Controlador del procesador de audio: N / A ID bus: 03: 00.5 Dispositivo-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio Proveedor: controlador ASUSTeK: snd_hda_intel v: ID de bus del kernel: 03: 00.6 Servidor de sonido: ALSA v: k5.4.0-47-generic

Red:

Dispositivo-1: Adaptador de red inalámbrica Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Proveedor: controlador AzureWave: ath10k_pci v: ID de bus del kernel: 01: 00.0 SI: wlp1s0 estado: arriba mac:

Unidades:

Almacenamiento local: total: 238,47 GiB usados: 15,03 GiB (6,3%) ID-1: / dev / nvme0n1 proveedor: Kingston modelo: RBUSNS8154P3256GJ3 tamaño: 238,47 GiB

Dividir:

ID-1: / tamaño: 87,69 GiB utilizado: 14,99 GiB (17,1%) fs: ext4 dev: / dev / nvme0n1p5

Sensores:

Temperaturas del sistema: CPU: 62,6 C mobo: N / A Velocidades del ventilador (RPM): CPU: 2800
```

By the way, It is a OS installed in a partition together with Windows 10.
I mean, the summary of my problem is that when I try to return from suspend, the screen keeps frozen and dark. On the other hand, the brightness cannot be moodified, no matter what you do